# Vimscript: Resolve variables to values before function invocation

Tags: vim

I apologize in advanced for what appears to be such a simple question.

I have a sample command defined as follows:

```
command! -nargs=+ Exmpl call Example(<f-args>)
function! Example(name)
    echo a:name
endfunc
```

It is invoked as follows:

```
Exmpl 'hello'
```

but it seems to literally interpret arguments given without parsing. So:

```
let hello = 'world'
Exmpl hello
```

Does not print `world`, as expected.

This is clearly something obvious I can't find in [the literature](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/24.html). I've tried adding a variety of escape characters like `&`, but the subsequent arguments are always treated as bare words.

How can I use variables in custom Vim commands?

Comment: You can use `:debug` to see what's really executed -> `:debug Exmpl hello` + `s` + ENTER + `s` + ENTER ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `<args>` instead of `<f-args>` does what you are asking.

**This command definition expands any supplied arguments when invoked**

```
command! -nargs=+ Example call Example(<args>)
function! Example(name)
      echo a:name
endfunc

let hello = 'world'
Exmpl hello
```

**Output**

```
world
```

**Reference**

```
:help command
```

then search the help text for: `/`<kbd>tab</kbd>`<args>`